# two dimensions with different dates in fact table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, data-warehouse

I'm trying to get around this but can't think of anything.

I have 5 dimensions two of which have different dates. Specifically,

```
TEMP_REQUEST
------------
temprequest_id
localcouncil_id
request_date
```

The other table is:

```
SESSION
--------
session_id
temprequest_id
session_date
status
.
.
```

Now I'm populating the fact using a cursor like this:

```
seq NUMBER;
 v_timeid NUMBER;

Cursor c_factable is
select  

  dw_localcouncil2.localcouncil_id,
  dw_session2.session_id,
  dw_temp2.temp_id,
  dw_temprequest2.temprequest_id,
  dw_typeoftempcover2.type_of_cover_id,
  dw_session2.session_date
from  DW_LOCALCOUNCIL2, DW_SESSION2, DW_TEMP2, DW_TEMPREQUEST2, DW_TYPEOFTEMPCOVER2
where dw_temprequest2.localcouncil_id = dw_localcouncil2.localcouncil_id AND
dw_session2.temprequest_id = dw_temprequest2.temprequest_id AND
dw_session2.temp_id = dw_temp2.temp_id AND
dw_session2.type_of_cover_id = dw_typeoftempcover2.type_of_cover_id;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('it is running!');
for c_rec in c_factable loop

SELECT time_id INTO v_timeid from dw_time
where session_date = c_rec.session_date;


insert into DW_SESSIONS_FACT values(v_timeid, c_rec.localcouncil_id, c_rec.session_id, c_rec.temp_id, c_rec.temprequest_id, c_rec.type_of_cover_id);

end loop;
```

My question is that the time_id field in the fact table corresponds to the session_date from the SESSION table and not for the TEMP_REQUEST table. Now If i wanted to query the fact table for a query such as this: `the number of temp requests by week!` I don't know how I would go about doing that with the current state of the fact table.

any help is greatly appreciated!

The time dimension has been generated and populated beforehand. Includes all dates between a start date to an end date. It contains the follow columns:

```
TIME_DIM
---------
time_id
session_date
t_day,
t_month,
t_year
```

Comment: Why not join the fact table with temp_request and place any type of condition you want on the date of the temp_request?

Comment: Not sure if I can do that. I mean say if wanted to get the number of sessions from I can just use the where condition: where dw_time.time_id = dw_sessions_fact.time_id     but i cannot use something like that for the temprequest_id in the fact table since time_id has been populated with the dates from only the SESSIONS table!

Comment: Why can't you add another column to the fact table that contains the session time_id?

Comment: i have time_id and i have session_id and i also have temprequest_id in fact table. The time_id is inserted based on the session_date column from the SESSION dimension. The temprequest_id is also a column in the SESSION dimension acting as a foreign key to the TEMP_REQUEST table. But the TEMP_REQUEST table has a request_date as well. And the time_id in the fact table corresponds only to the session_id not the temprequest_id. Look at the insert command in the code!

Comment: The TEMP_REQUEST table has about 87 entries(i.e. dates) , SESSION table has about 357 entries (i.e. dates) how do  i make the time_id in the fact table correspond to both of these separately somehow. Currently, it's only corresponding to the session_id and not temprequest_id. I'm not sure how to do this, that's what i need help in doing.

Comment: The number of temp requests by week: SELECT TRUNC(TR.REQUEST_DATE,'IW') WEEK_START_DATE, COUNT(*) FROM TEMP_REQUEST TR JOIN FACT F USING(TEMP_REQUEST_ID) GROUP BY TRUNC(TR.REQUEST_DATE,'IW')

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to have multiple time id's in your fact table. Add another column for the TRANSACTION time as per @ElectricLlam's comment

```
ALTER TABLE DW_SESSIONS_FACT ADD REQUEST_TIMEID int NULL
```

Then, keeping with your current method of getting time_ids

```
SELECT time_id INTO v_timeid_transaction from dw_time
where session_date = c_rec.request_date;
```

I'm not sure why your time_dim table has an explicit reference to SESSION in its date/time field. Your time dimension should be stand alone so it can be referenced by any date field.

In summary:

Tables:

```
TIME_DIM
---------
time_id
d_date   --(date/timestamp datatype)
t_day
t_month
t_year

TEMP_REQUEST
------------
temprequest_id
localcouncil_id
request_date  

SESSION
--------
session_id
temprequest_id
session_date
status

DW_SESSIONS_FACT
----------------
session_timeid, 
request_timeid,
localcouncil_id, 
session_id, 
temp_id, 
temprequest_id, 
type_of_cover_id
```

And your etl procedure:

```
seq NUMBER;
v_timeid_session NUMBER;
v_timeid_request NUMBER;

Cursor c_factable is
select  

  dw_localcouncil2.localcouncil_id,
  dw_session2.session_id,
  dw_temp2.temp_id,
  dw_temprequest2.temprequest_id,
  dw_typeoftempcover2.type_of_cover_id,
  dw_session2.session_date,
  dw_temprequest2.request_date
from  DW_LOCALCOUNCIL2, DW_SESSION2, DW_TEMP2, DW_TEMPREQUEST2, DW_TYPEOFTEMPCOVER2
where dw_temprequest2.localcouncil_id = dw_localcouncil2.localcouncil_id AND
dw_session2.temprequest_id = dw_temprequest2.temprequest_id AND
dw_session2.temp_id = dw_temp2.temp_id AND
dw_session2.type_of_cover_id = dw_typeoftempcover2.type_of_cover_id;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('it is running!');
for c_rec in c_factable loop

--You can do these joins directly in your c_factable query, it would be much faster
--and you could remove the need for a cursor..
SELECT time_id INTO v_timeid_session from dw_time
where d_date = c_rec.session_date;

SELECT time_id INTO v_timeid_request from dw_time
where d_date = c_rec.request_date;


insert into DW_SESSIONS_FACT values(v_timeid_session, v_timeid_request , c_rec.localcouncil_id, c_rec.session_id, c_rec.temp_id, c_rec.temprequest_id, c_rec.type_of_cover_id);

end loop;
```