# populate a fact table and time table with one cursor

Tags: sql, cursor

Could any one please tell me how to populate a a fact table and time table with one cursor. The tables are as follows,

**DW_TERM_FACT** TABLE

```
TERM_ID
BRANCH_ID
TEMPREQUEST_ID
TEMPCOVER_ID
TEMP_ID
STATUS
TERMDATE
```

**DW_TIME** TABLE

```
TIME_ID
TDATE
TWEEK
TMONTH
TYEAR
```

thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you done so far to solve your problem?

Comment: I declared a cursor but it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Follow below you should be ok.

```
declare Cur_Details cursor
for
    --select your details you will be populating from
open Cur_Details
fetch next from Cur_Details
    into  -- insert into your variables that you will use
while @@Fetch_Status = 0
   Begin
        if -- your variable meets your criteria you can begin your table population
           Begin
           --populate your tables using variables that you populated from cursor
           End
Fetch next from Cur_Details
    into -- insert into your variables that you will use
End
close Cur_Details
deallocate Cur_Details
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485674/two-dimensions-with-different-dates-in-fact-table/27393916#27393916